# Write a Matlab program but cant find the Excel file

Tags: matlab

I used these commands:

```
data_save(:,1) = t';  

data_save(:,2) = Er';  

xlswrite('THz222.xlsx', data_save)
```

want to know how to open the `excel` file with the saved data

Comment: Um, did you try opening `THz222.xlsx` with excel?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand you correctly, but the excel file should be in the same directory as the current directory you are working in in Matlab. You can also define the path you want to save the file at when using

```
xlswrite('/your_path/THz222.xlsx', data_save)
```

where you should replace your_path with whatever path you want to save the file at. Does this answer your question?